# Test a controller with Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I had some trouble setting up unit test with my spring boot application. My main issue is with the "model" object that's needed in my controller, but I can't find a way to recreate it in my test, which is required to use my function.

here are the function I want to test

```
@Controller
public class AjoutAbscenceControler {

  @Autowired
  private AbsenceRepository absenceRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = { "/addAbsence" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showAddAbsencePage(Model model) {

    Absence absence = new Absence();
    model.addAttribute("Absence", absence);

    return "addAbsence";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = { "/addingAbsence" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String saveAbsence(Model model, @ModelAttribute("absence") Absence absence) {

    if (absence.getName() != null && absence.getName().length() > 0) {
      absenceRepository.save(absence);
    }
    return "redirect:/userList";
  }

}
```

I did try something like that

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AjoutAbscenceControlerTest {

  @Mock
  VacationRepository vacationRepository;
  @Mock
  CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
  @InjectMocks
  AjoutAbscenceControler controler;
  public MockMvc mockMvc;
  @Before
  public  void  setUp() throws Exception{
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controler).build();
  }
  @Test
  public void showAddAbsencePagetest() {
  AjoutAbscenceControler ajoutAbscenceControler =new AjoutAbscenceControler();

    assertEquals("addAbsence",ajoutAbscenceControler.showAddAbsencePage(controler));
  }
}
```

but I don't find any way to create a `springfarmwork.ui.Model`

Comment: That doesn't make much sense: you're mocking two repositories that aren't used by your controller, but you're not mocking the one that is used. You're asking Mockito to create the controller and inject mocks for you, but then you create another instance by yourself. Regarding creating a Model, [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) gives the list of all classes implementing this interface.

Comment: Also, Absence is spelt Absense, not Abscence, and Controller is spelt Controller (in English), or Controleur (in French), but not Controler.

Comment: Using `MockMvc` you do not have to call methods of controllers, but rather simulate an HTTP request through the `MockMvc` API. Doing this, the `Model` parameter will be be built and injected by **Spring**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing the logic of your controller you probably shouldn't create a `Model` object, but mock it, and verify the interactions against it:

```
@Mock
private Model model;

@Test
public void showAddAbsencePagetest() {
    // Should probably be initialized in a @Before method,
    // Initialized here for clarity only
    AjoutAbscenceControler ajoutAbscenceControler = new AjoutAbscenceControler();

    assertEquals("addAbsence", ajoutAbscenceControler.showAddAbsencePage(model));

    Mockito.verify(model).addAttribute(eq("Absence"), any(Absence.class));
}
```

Comment: thx, it work. i had some trouble cause intelij doesn't import the good any and eq by itself, but anyway, nice work!